# Are matrices commutable if $ABv=BAv$?

Tags: matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are both $n \times n$ matrices, and $v$ is a non-zero $n \times 1$ column vector then is it true that if
$$ABv = BAv$$
then $$AB=BA$$

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe look at small cases (n = 2 or 3) and see what happens?

Comment: It's not enough to check it for a single random $v$. But if $Xv=Yv$ _for all_ $v$ of the right shape, then $X=Y$. (In particular with $X=AB$ and $Y=BA$).

Comment: If $ABv = BAv$ for $n$ linearly independent $v$, then $AB = BA$.

Comment: No. Here's a counterexample. Let $A = \left(\matrix{2 && 2\\2 && 2}\right), B = \left(\matrix{1 && 5\\ 2 && 4}\right)$ and $v = \left(\matrix{1 \\ 1}\right).$ We have $ABv = BAv = \left(\matrix{24 \\ 24}\right).$ But $AB = \left(\matrix{6 && 18\\6 && 18}\right)$ and $BA = \left(\matrix{12 && 12\\12 && 12}\right).$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is NO.

You cannot say $AB = BA$ if $ABv = BAv$ for some vector $v$.

However, if $ABv = BAv$ is true for all vectors $v$ (or) at-least for $n$ linearly independent vectors $v$, then it is true that $AB = BA$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $AB = C.$ Then we have $ABv= Cv =BAv$ for all $v.$

Do you feel comfortable saying $BA = C$ now? Do you know any theorems about the uniqueness of matrices of linear transformations under fixed bases?

Edit: In Light of the other answer, i should clarify, this is true only *for all* $v.$

Comment: I have not had very much exposure to linear algebra, and I'm not even sure what "linear transformations under fixed bases" really means.

Comment: Well, then I would take the route suggested in the comments above instead of worrying about uniqueness of matrices (this theorem was introduced early in *my* linear algebra course, so i turn to it i guess!)